# Netbeans Java EE project with layers on different machine

Tags: jakarta-ee, netbeans, ejb

The goal is creating a simple Java EE 6 application with EJBs deployed on a machine and the web part on a different machine. I'm using Glassfish and Netbeans 7.2 but I get confused about the dependencies between the two parts.

I've created an Enterprise Application Project and Netbeans 7.2 started splitting the project in a war part and a jar part. As the two should be deployed into two different machines (two Glassfish servers) I used the Remote option when creating the first EJB but Netbeans asked me for a Remote Project. Should I create a library containing the remote interfaces? And in that case, should the war part use it? (It seems the war jsf managed bean is already able to import the interfaces so I get confused).

All the Netbeans tutorials I've read don't mention Remote Interfaces when the client is a web application but only when the client is an enterprise client application. Which is the correct way to develop Java EE multilayered application with web components and ejb components?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you must create one more project for remote interfaces, otherwise you could not call EJB's

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You need to create e "EJB Client" jar with all the required (Remote)business interfaces / exceptions and Travel Objects (TO).

If you use maven you can find here a good documentation how to create such one:
https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ejb-plugin/examples/generating-ejb-client.html

then on your war/WEB-INF/lib contains only the client-jar and all other required jars for your application, but not the jars containing your EJB Service implementations. these are deployed inside your EAR/lib folder on the other machine. the client-jar must only exist on your web machine class path.

BTW: If you use maven. have a look at an example maven structure on GitHub:
https://github.com/StefanHeimberg/stackoverflow-1134894/. It is not a example for a "splitted" architecure, but i think it could be informativ. or simple ignore it :)